# Change the port of IIS 7.5 Express

Tags: iis

I have just installed IIS 7.5 Express (via VS 2010 SP1), now the sites in IIS 5.1 won't start.

I think it might be because IIS 7.5 Express is using port 80. I'm trying to change the bindings, however I don't think you can use the IIS7 manager to connect to 7.5 Express.

Any ideas? Or am I barking up the wrong tree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems it wasn't IIS 7.5 Express at all, but the Web Deployment Agent Service.

After stopping it, I was able to start the site in IIS 5.1.

But thanks @taspeotis for your answer.

EDIT:

After doing some more research into why the Web Deployment Agent Service is on port 80, I came across this:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd569059(WS.10).aspx

With a specific mention to:

> If you install Web Deploy by using the
>   Windows UI, the Web Deploy remote
>   service will listen on
>   http://+:80/MsDeployAgentService/. On
>   Windows XP, you will have to change
>   either the default port for the agent
>   service, or change the port for the
>   default Web site. On later versions of
>   Windows, the Web Deploy remote service
>   will not conflict with IIS on port 80,
>   and IIS and the Web Deploy remote
>   service can run at the same time. Web
>   Deploy and IIS both use the HTTP.SYS
>   URL registrations to make reservations
>   in the URL namespace. To install Web
>   Deploy with a different remote service
>   URL, see the Installing from the
>   Command Line section in this topic.

Answer (score 1):

You should find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4690358/iisexpress-user-interface) helpful.

Comment: Thanks @taspeotis for your answer, I've voted it up, but it looks like it wasn't IIS 7.5 Express's fault after all and instead the Web Deployment Agent Service. Thanks for the tip thought, its good to know.